# C# Textbox enters info but leaves a ' * ' in textbox

Tags: c#, sql, windows, text, textbox

I have a registration system, where people scan barcodes and logs them in. The barcodes hold a unique number following a '*'. When they scan their code it enters into the listbox and clears the remainder out of the textbox, but, it is not clearing the ' * '.

Any ideas ? Here is the chuck of code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
        Object returnValue;

        string txtend = textBox1.Text;
        returnValue = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"*", "");

        if (e.KeyChar != '*') return;
        {
          if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
           {
             for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
              {
               string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
               if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
               {
                //listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
               }
             }
           }
          else
          listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);
          textBox1.Clear();
          System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
          foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
          sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
          sw.Flush();
          sw.Close();
          if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
          else
          {
            EnableCloseButton();
          }
          label6.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar != '*') return;` looks suspicious already.

Comment: Proper use of braces and whitespaces can save lifes :)

Comment: +1 dowhilefor. It's hard to tell if you're seeing problems due to if/else statements being inadvertently executed or if that's actually how it's supposed to be.

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar != '*') return;` is required to determine the end of the barcodes code. It does work correctly, just  pain to see the '*' still sitting there.

Comment: braces or curly brackets are the symbols you use to define code blocks { } ... Sometimes you can omit them, like in an if statement. But important to know is, that an if statement without curly braces only uses the next statement. You used an if statement without braces (because of the following return;) and then used directly curly braces below the if, which is btw. fine and is sometimes used for scoping. So it looks like its part of the if, but its not. Therefore: Proper use of braces and whitespaces will save your life, and a lot of debugging ;) (answer to deleted comment)

Comment: great help @dowhilefor !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rereading your question I understood that after processing the '*' it was inserted into the empty textbox.

To stop the handling of the key up event use this statement:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

This indicated that the event was handled by your code and should not be processed further.

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Many thanks, would +1 but need higher rep haha !Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
if (e.KeyChar != '*') return;
```

ends the event handling early when the pressed Key is not '*'. With the following { } Block it looks like an old/testing relict.

Also there are maybe some problems with the `else` after the first `if`-Block. I recommend to use { } always, even when there is only one line in the block.

Comment: Agreed with the `if {}` rules. My hard/fast rules are - if the first block is a single statement without braces then the else block can also be a single statement without braces. If the first block covers multiple lines, it feels more readable to enclose else blocks in braces too, regardless of the number of statements.

Comment: Cheers guys, I have changed the braces on the if/else statement. 
Also referring to that code, it will always be '*' , so there is no problem with that, if there is no '*' then it does not progress with the code, it will skip it

Comment: @RyanGillooly Not directly the missing braces but the `return` statement in the line in my answer is the problem. The `return` statement is executed every time the typed char is not '*', resulting in leaving the function!

Comment: I understand this, but I can type anything I like in the textbox, up to any amount of characters i like, but as soon as I hit '*' it then enters it.